# How do I resolve this error "message": "Endpoint request timed out" when deploying a Django application to AWS via lambda?

Tags: django, aws-lambda

I'm deploying my Django application (backend) to AWS via lambda, but each time I deploy and get the live link, I get the error below:

**{
"message": "Endpoint request timed out"
}**

I have configured the VPC. I have also set the "timeout_seconds": 900, which is the max time that AWS Lambda supports. But the error persists.

How can I resolve this, please?

Comment: Welcome to SE. I think we need more information to answer your question. Are you sending a request to your endpoint and it is timing out? Or is this happening when you are deploying your lambda function?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. This is happening when I'm running the application. 
So it deploys successfully but when I run that URL that's when I get that error.

Comment: There are two potential causes. First, your API might be misconfigured (for example, doesn't return a response), and it's times out before return a response. Second, your endpoint might not be accessible, so it never ever hits Django. You should test to see if Django's being contacted at all by looking at your logs. Sorry I can't be more helpful -- I do not know Lambda.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that all configurations were ok. The only issues was that there was a request that was being sent to another API at the point of running the application. So that caused the error. So I stopped invoking that function at the point of running the application.